# Error: Specified basePath has to start with a /, found "." Next JS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js

I want to put '.' in my baseurl but I've gotten this error `Error: Specified basePath has to start with a /, found "."`

```
    const nextConfig = {
  basePath: '.',
  reactStrictMode: true,

}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

in next.config.js

Answer (score 0):

You can just omit the `basePath` option if you want to set it to `.`. There's no need to set `basePath` in that scenario.